# OnClickListener onLongClickListener logic

Tags: android, onclicklistener

Recently I started proggraming from scratch and I'm learning from thenewboston's tutorials and I dont really get how it works and I cant find any answers. Thats the code Im struggling with, it works but i dont really get why there is beetwen () brackets an  new Button.OnClick listener and then  OnLongClickListener where does the View v come from in these methods ?? Ye my knowledge about object programming  may be a bit smaller than its required but I dont really like learning other way than using this.

```
Button przycisk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mojprzycisk);

    przycisk.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) { WHERE THIS  V IS FROM ?
                    TextView mojtekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mojtekst);
                    mojtekst.setText("Good job Boss");

                }
            }


    );
    przycisk.setOnLongClickListener(
            new Button.OnLongClickListener() {

                public boolean onLongClick(View v){   <-----WHERE IS IT FROM?
                    TextView mojtekst = (TextView)   findViewById(R.id.mojtekst);
                    mojtekst.setText("HOLY CARP THAT WAS A LONG ONE");
                return true;}}



    );
```

Comment: That `View v` is the `View` such as `Button` and `ImageButton` you clicked/long clicked on.

Comment: where is it in this code ?  and why we put beetwen ()  a lot of methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into [interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/interface.html) for java. A great tutorial for the same is also given [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/interfaces.html). Once you understand the concepts of interfaces, you can see that [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) and [OnLongClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html) are interfaces, and they have methods like [onClick(View v)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html#onClick(android.view.View)) and [onLongClick(View v)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener.html#onLongClick(android.view.View)), that are invoked when a particular view has been clicked or long clicked. They return back the view that was clicked and held.

When you say

```
przycisk.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) { WHERE THIS  V IS FROM ?
                    TextView mojtekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mojtekst);
                    mojtekst.setText("Good job Boss");

                }
            }


    );
```

You are creating a new instance of the interface. The above code for easy readability can be also be written as follows.

```
Button.OnClickListener onClickListener = new Button.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        TextView mojtekst = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mojtekst);
        mojtekst.setText("Good job Boss");
    }
};
przycisk.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
```

So basically you're creating an instance of the interface, and since its an interface you need to override the method `onClick()` and give its definition.

In short to whichever view you set the `onClickListener` or the `onLongClickListener`, that view would be returned in the `onClick(View v)` and `onLongClick(View v)` methods. That view would be the `v`.

Comment: wow yea I got it thanks for the links.CaveOfProgramming mentioned about it I had to forget or I didnt understand him properly which made me forget...